# What does "which" refer to in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases

> This is a feature of a computer which is new in the market.

Does the above mean that the feature is new in the market or that the computer is new in the market or both the feature and the computer are new in the market. Or are they ambiguous?

And how do sentences structured like this behave?

Comment: Yes it's ambiguous. The feature is probably 'new'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally, it is ambiguous. The sense is probably that the feature is new, since there's nothing very remarkable about a new computer on the market. There are many computers.
If that is what was intended, it would be better put as
"This computer has a feature which is new in the market."

The other sense could be expressed by
"This computer, which is new in the market, has X as a feature."

Comment: Thank you very much